# Extraer de una cadena letras y símbolo teniendo en cuenta unicode en Android

Tags: java, android, regex

Tengo la siguiente función que elimina de una cadena todo los caracteres que no sean `#` , `a..Z`

`String.replaceAll("[^#A-Za-z]", "");`

Pero me encuentro que si la cadena tienes caracteres del alfabeto cirílico, griego, árabe etc... pues me los elimina.

¿Hay alguna forma para poder referir todos los carácteres alfabéticos, descartando todos los otros y numéricos y solo permitir `#`?

```
origen           resultado
-------------------------------
yolanda perez => yolandaperez
#+34668555555 => #
Пивоварова    => Пивоварова
հայեր         => հայեր
አማሪኮ         => አማሪኮ
kiểm tra      => kiểmtra
ตรวจสอบ       => ตรวจสอบ
التحقق من <=    التحقق من
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, deseas eliminar únicamente los números ypermitir obtener todos los caracteres no numéricos.

Comment: es decir solo obtener los caracteres alfabeticos de a-z pero contemplando unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede utilizar la clase de caracteres `\p{L}`. Es decir:

```
String.replaceAll("[^#\\p{L}]", "")
```

Una alternativa es utilizar la clase de caracteres POSIX `\p{Alpha}` y la bandera `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`.<sup>(1)</sup> Es decir:

```
Pattern.compile("[^#\\p{Alpha}]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)
       .matcher(input)
       .replaceAll("")
```

---

*Notas*

1. Esta bandera no tiene ningún efecto en Android, las clases de caracteres Unicode siempre se utilizan.

Comment: Excelente respuesta Paul... ¿Tenés la fuente para la info que agregaste en la nota? (No estoy en el mundo Android y me interesa leerlo)

Comment: @Mariano Gracias. La fuente es la siguiente: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Eliminar todos los caracteres no numéricos, sin eliminar caracteres del alfabeto cirílico, griego, árabe etc, se puede lograr usando:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\\d.]", "");
```

en el ejemplo que muestras únicamente eliminaría los numericos:

```
yolanda perez => yolandaperez
#+            => #
Пивоварова    => Пивоварова
հայեր         => հայեր
አማሪኮ         => አማሪኮ
kiểm tra      => kiểmtra
ตรวจสอบ       => ตรวจสอบ
التحقق من <=    التحقق من
```